# How to define the variable scope in gitlabci yaml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a two branch in gitlab called **master** and **dev**.

Master points to production and dev points to testing.

Master used a set a variable which are different from dev.

So I configured the **environments** in the repo. When defining variables I am able to assign the scope for the enviorments.

**My question is how can i define that scope in gitlab-ci.yml.**

so is there a way to define the scope for all stages at once instead of defining for each stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as the [environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) can only defined per job.